# Avoid Flexdashboard pages in same project share objects

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have two reports made in flexdashboards inside the same project.
The only difference is the data source and data wrangling is the same for both. Object names are same because code is really a copy (the only different lines are for data load, filtered by country).

Every chunk has this option to force fresh data always.

```
r cache=FALSE
```

Accessing my flexdashboard

> Germany.Rmd

renders ok

But if I open the other flexdashboard

> France.Rmd

the data and charts are from Germany.

I suppose the objects (df, plot..) having the same name are conflicting even with no cache.

Is there any way of solving this issue to avoid creating a project for every country?

Comment: Instead of using `chache = FALSE` in every chunk, use once at the beginning of the documents `knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = FALSE)`. You can also delete the folder where eventually plots were stored.

Comment: sorry, but is behaving the same. Tables are shown with data from the report loaded in the first place. No matter if I change the option chunk command and deleted folder with plots (i just use one plot). Maybe I shoul change object names to avoid conflicts or, much better, create a project per country..?